# Python Pandas Dataframe, merge df rows while skipping overlapping rows

Tags: python, pandas, merge

The title doesn't make a clear sense, but it was the best I could describe.

I have DataFrames that look like these:

```
data1 = np.matrix([[4,75,2,5,84,2,6,5,554],[4,6,67,6,4,5,8,5,8]]).T
data2 = np.matrix([[3,46,4,555,556,557,558,559,560],[1,2,4,1,3,5,3,1,5]]).T

data1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
data2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)

>>> data1
     0   1
0    4   4
1   75   6
2    2  67
3    5   6
4   84   4
5    2   5
6    6   8
7    5   5
8  554   8


>>> data2
     0  1
0    3  1
1   46  2
2    4  4
3  555  1
4  556  3
5  557  5
6  558  3
7  559  1
8  560  5
```

I want to append `data2` to the bottom of `data1`. However, I want to append rows of `data2` whose column1 values are greater than or equal to the `554`, which is the last row of column1 of `data1`

Here is the output I want:

```
>>> merged_df
         0   1
    0    4   4
    1   75   6
    2    2  67
    3    5   6
    4   84   4
    5    2   5
    6    6   8
    7    5   5
    8  554   8
    9  555   1
   10  556   3
   11  557   5
   12  558   3
   13  559   1
   14  560   5
```

So, some of the first rows of `data2` will be skipped when appending to `data1`.

It is assumed that the last row of `data1` is its maximum, and the rows of `data2` are sorted after the last value of `data1`, which is `554`

Is there any elegant way to do this job using Pandas toolbox?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) with filter second `DataFrame` by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
print (data1.iloc[-1, 0])
554

df = pd.concat([data1, data2[data2[0] > data1.iloc[-1, 0]]], ignore_index=True)
print (df)
      0   1
0     4   4
1    75   6
2     2  67
3     5   6
4    84   4
5     2   5
6     6   8
7     5   5
8   554   8
9   555   1
10  556   3
11  557   5
12  558   3
13  559   1
14  560   5
```

Also for general solution compare by `max` value:

```
df = pd.concat([data1, data2[data2[0] > data1[0].max()]], ignore_index=True)
```

Solution if custom columns names:

```
data1 = pd.DataFrame(data1, columns=list('ab'))
data2 = pd.DataFrame(data2, columns=list('ab'))

print (data1.iloc[-1, data1.columns.get_loc('a')])
554

data22 = data2[data2['a'] > data1.iloc[-1, data1.columns.get_loc('a')]]
df = pd.concat([data1, data22], ignore_index=True)
print (df)
      a   b
0     4   4
1    75   6
2     2  67
3     5   6
4    84   4
5     2   5
6     6   8
7     5   5
8   554   8
9   555   1
10  556   3
11  557   5
12  558   3
13  559   1
14  560   5
```

Comment: @EricKim - Glad can help!